# Loop won't execute in python program

Tags: python

```
class Employee:

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_IDnumber(self, IDnumber):
        self.IDnumber = IDnumber

    def set_department(self, deparment):
        self.deparment = deparment

    def set_jobTitle(self, jobTitle):
        self.jobTitle = jobTitle

    def get_name(self):
        # Returns name
        return self.name

    def get_IDnumber(self):
        # Returns IDnumber
        return self.IDnumber

    def get_department(self):
        # Returns department
        return self.department

    def get_jobTitle(self):
        # Returns job title
        return self.jobTitle

def make_list():
    employee_list = []
    print("Enter data for 3 employees")
    for i in range(1, 4):
        print('Employee ' + str(i))
        name = input('Enter employee name: ')
        idNumber = int(input('Enter employee ID number: '))
        department = input('Enter employee department: ')
        jobTitle = input('Enter job title: ')
        employee = Employee()
        employee.set_name(name)
        employee.set_IDnumber(idNumber)
        employee.set_department(department)
        employee.set_jobTitle(jobTitle)
        employee_list.append(employee)
        print(i)
        return employee_list


def main():
    make_list()

main()
```

The program runs fine. However the issue I'm running into is that the programs stops after one iteration of the loop, therefore I can only input the information for one employee. Can anyone please tell me why it's only iterating once instead of 3 times for the 3 employees? Thanks a ton.

Comment: u r supposed to edit the indentation for the line "return employee_list" . this is the one which is returning after each loop execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the return statement. The return statement is inside the loop and it should be outside the loop.

Make_list function should be replaced with the following code.

```
def make_list():
    employee_list = []
    print("Enter data for 3 employees")
    for i in range(1, 4):
        print('Employee ' + str(i))
        name = input('Enter employee name: ')
        idNumber = int(input('Enter employee ID number: '))
        department = input('Enter employee department: ')
        jobTitle = input('Enter job title: ')
        employee = Employee()
        employee.set_name(name)
        employee.set_IDnumber(idNumber)
        employee.set_department(department)
        employee.set_jobTitle(jobTitle)
        employee_list.append(employee)
        print(i)
    return employee_list
```